Show that $\Delta \in \mathbb{B}_X \otimes \mathbb{B}_X$ but $\Delta \not \in S \otimes S$.
Let $(X, d)$ separable space. Recall that $\Delta := \{(x, x): x \in X\}$ and that $\mathbb{B}_X := \sigma(\tau_d)$.
I will firstly show that $\Delta \in \mathbb{B}_X \otimes \mathbb{B}_X$, but I don't clearly see where the separability of $X$ is supposed to be used.
Theorem. Let $(X, \mathcal{P}_1)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{P}_2)$ be two measurable spaces. If $E_1 \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ and $E_2 \subseteq \mathscr{P}(Y)$ are such that $X \in E_1$, $Y \in E_2$, $\sigma(E_1) = \mathcal{P}_1$ and $\sigma(E_2) = \mathcal{P}_2$, then
$$\mathcal{P}_1 \otimes \mathcal{P}_2 = \sigma(E_1 \times E_2)$$
Thus, since $X \in \tau_d \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ by definition of topology and $\mathbb{B}_X := \sigma(\tau_d)$, we have that
$$\mathbb{B}_X \otimes \mathbb{B}_X = \sigma(\tau_d \times \tau_d)$$
By the other hand, since $(X, d)$ is metric space (which is Hausdorff), $\Delta$ is a closed set in $(X \times X, \tau_d \times \tau_d)$. That is, $(X \times X) \setminus \Delta \in \tau_d \times \tau_d$, but $\tau_d \times \tau_d \subseteq \sigma(\tau_d \times \tau_d)$ and, since a sigma algebra is closed under measurable sets differences, $\Delta \in \mathbb{B}_X \otimes \mathbb{B}_X$.

Now, suppose that $X$ is only a uncountable set. Let
$$S := \{A \subseteq X: A \text{ or } X \setminus A \text{ is finite or countable} \}$$
which is a sigma algebra of $X$. Now I want to show that $\Delta \not \in S \otimes S$.
Theorem. Let $E \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X)$ fixed. Then, foreach $A \in \sigma(E)$, there is a countable  subset $E_0 \subseteq E$ such that $A \in \sigma(E_0)$.
For rising to a contradiction, suppose that $\Delta \in S \otimes S$. Since $S \otimes S \subseteq \mathscr{P}(X \times X)$, there is a countable set $E \subseteq S \otimes S$ such that $\Delta \in \sigma(E)$.
I don't know how to arrive to the contradiction.

EDIT.
I found some valuable work here, so could I solve problem 2. But I still haven't an answer for question 1.
A question about $\sigma$-Algebra determine whether the diagonal it is measurable.

For question 1: Since $\mathbb{B}(\tau_d) := \Sigma(\tau_d)$, you only have $\mathbb{B}(\tau_d) \otimes \mathbb{B}(\tau_d) = \Sigma(\tau_d) \otimes \Sigma(\tau_d)$. In order to have $\Sigma(\tau_d) \otimes \Sigma(\tau_d) = \Sigma(\tau_d \times \tau_d)$ you need the the separable property of $X$.

@Ramiro I updated the post with the theorem that I used to proof that claim. Can you have a look?

I think you are making a subtle mistake in "type." A set of tuples $A \times B$ is not the same thing as a tuple of sets $(A,B)$. Specifically, let $A$ be an element of the collection of sets $E$. Let $B$ be an element of the collection of sets $E'$. Then \begin{align}&(A,B)\in E \times E'\&(A,B) \in \Sigma(E)\times \Sigma(E')\&A \times B \in \Sigma(E)\otimes\Sigma(E')\end{align} where I use $\Sigma(E)$ to denote the sigma algebra on $X$ generated by sets in $E$.

@Michael I cannot get your point, I have that $\mathbb{E} \subseteq S \otimes S$. So, if $x \in \mathbb{E}$, then it is of the form $x = A \times B$, for some $A, B \in S$. So, $\mathbb{E} = {A_{t_n} \times B_{s_n} }_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X \times X)$.

Your above comment seems to make a different mistake: If $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra on a set $X$ then $\mathcal{F}\otimes\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra on $X\times X$. Not all sets in $\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{F}$ are of the form $A \times B$ for some $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and $B \in \mathcal{F}$. For example, there are sets in the Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$ that cannot be expressed as $A \times B$. This is a different point from the more subtle issue that $(A,B)$ is not the same type of thing as $A \times B$.

@Michael I got it: The characterization of $E$ is not rightly noted. By the other hand I use $\mathcal{P}$, or rawly written '\mathcal{P}', for power set, not for a sigma algebra. Which means that I'm writing it wrong. Thanks!!

For question 1: I see what is happening. There is a issue of notation. The symbol $\tau_d \times \tau_d$ is NOT the product topology, but the set of rectangles ${ U \times V : U, V \in \tau_d }$. With this definition, you are right:
$$\mathbb{B}(\tau_d) \otimes \mathbb{B}(\tau_d) = \sigma(\tau_d) \otimes \Sigma(\tau_d)= \sigma(\tau_d \times \tau_d)$$ and you are right: proving that $\Delta \in \mathbb{B}_X \otimes \mathbb{B}_X$ does NOT depend on the separability of $X$. (continue)

The separability of $X$ is only needed if we want to prove that: if $\tau_{X \times X}$ is the product topology, then $\mathbb{B}(\tau_{X \times X})= \mathbb{B}(\tau_d) \otimes \mathbb{B}(\tau_d)$, or in a simpler notation: $\mathbb{B}_{X \times X}= \mathbb{B}_X \otimes \mathbb{B}_X$.

@Ramiro Thank you very much! These appreciations are essential to improving knowledge.
